# Relation between Covariance and Energy of a random signal

Tags: probability, random-variables, signal-processing

Let's say I have the below random signal: $Y[n]=[y(n)y(n−1)y(n−2)....y(1)]$

I have two random variables now: The first one $X_1$ which express the maximum eigenvalue of the covariance matrix of $Y$. The second one $X_2$ which express the energy of the random signal.

Now my question is: Are the two random variables independent or dependent ,when whether signal samples : $y(n),y(n−1)....$are IID or correlated with each other.

By intuition the two random variables should be correlated !? isn't it right!?

Comment: They are dependent since, if I remember correctly, $X_2$ is the trace of the covariance matrix divided by $n$. The trace is also the sum of the eigenvalues. Hence, I agree with you that there should be a statistical dependence.

Comment: I think that $X_2$ is the trace of the covariance matrix when signal samples $y(n) y(n-1)....$ are IID only , Am I right !?     
and do you think it is easy to find the correlation between this two random variables !?      
@Bernhard

Comment: Hmm, good question. The covariance matrix of $Y[n]$ has the entries $\mathbb{E}(y^2(n))$, ..., $\mathbb{E}(y^2(1))$ as entries, doesn't it? And the energy is the exactly the sum of these entries, regardless whether we talk about iid entries or not. I think you can at least show that $X_2$ has to be larger than $X_1$, can't you? That is already some kind of statistical dependence...

Comment: let me ask you last question, noting that I am a telecom engineer not a mathematician 
if $X_2$ was the energy of the first K samples only $y(1) y(2) ... y(k)$,     
while $X_1$ is the Sample Covariance Matrix of L samples$y(1) y(2)..y(L)$ (L is the smoothing factor)and then averaged over the whole signal Y(n).              

If N >> K >> L Is it possible to consider $X_1 , X_2$ as independent then !? @Bernhard